# how to get only <html> data </html> from internet using java?

Tags: java, html

I'm using following code for retrieving data from internet but I get HTTP headers also which is useless for me.

```
URL url = new URL(webURL);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            in.close();
```

how can I get html data only not any headers or whatsoever.

regards

Comment: Can you show the output? You should not be getting the headers with this. The headers are obtained by conn.getHeader() (or something like that). The InputStream should be only the data in the request. It's possible that header-like things are in the body of the request.

Comment: Use html parser - jsoup.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving and parsing a document using [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/):

```
Parser p = new Parser();
SAX2DOM sax2dom = new SAX2DOM();
URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");
p.setContentHandler(sax2dom);
p.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())));
org.w3c.dom.Node doc = sax2dom.getDOM();
```

The TagSoup and SAX2DOM packages are:

```
import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser;
import org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM;
```

Writing the contents to `System.out`:

```
TransformerFactory tFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFact.newTransformer();
Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
Result result = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

These all come from `import javax.xml.transform.*`

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving correct data using URLConnecton. However if you want to read/access a particular html tag you must have to use HTML parser. I suggest you to use [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/download).

Example:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect("http://your_url/").get();
org.jsoup.nodes.Element head=doc.head(); // <head> tag content
org.jsoup.nodes.Element body=doc.body(); // <body> tag content

System.out.println(doc.text()); // Only text inside the <html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are meaning to translate html into text? If so, you can use `org.htmlparser.*`. Take a loo at http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If you answer a question, please use complete sentences.

Comment: Sorry,I'm a greenhand at this wensite. I'll improve my skills of answering.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the complete data to search for the string  and accept the data only between html tags